# Sylius - browser not loading latest version of my CSS file

Tags: css, symfony, uglifyjs, sylius, uglifycss

We have a Sylius stack where we have installed uglify for minifying CSS and JS files.

Since then, some of us in the team are facing issues with the browser not getting the latest version of the assets files.

In my web/CSS I do see the latest version of my public/css/style.css which technically means it gets correctly minified by uglify.

However in the browser I see the old version of the file itself. I made sure to clean cache and local storage in my browser, but still no luck. Any idea of what might be causing the issue?